# How to select next/previous anchor tags in a DIV with down/up arrow keys?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an `<input id="#locKeySearch">` and a `<div id="#locDropDown">`. When I type in my `input` field I call a dynamic drop down through AJAX in the `div`.

Now I would like to have more functionality from the arrow keys <kbd>↓</kbd>/<kbd>↑</kbd>. I want to select my `<a>` tags and when they are selected their backgrounds change and on pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the browser navigates to the appropriate location.

Can anyone help me on this please?

CSS:

```
div {width:300px;}
a{display:block;}
a:hover{background:#ccc;}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#locKeySearch').keydown(function(e)
    {<br>
      var alinks = $('#locDropDown').find('a');
      if(alinks.length > 0)
      {
        alinks.each(function(){

          if (e.keyCode === 40)//Down Arrow
          {
              e.preventDefault();
              var current = alinks.index(),
              next = $(this).next();
              this.blur();
              setTimeout(function() { next.focus().select(); }, 50);
          }
        });
      }
    });
  });
```

HTML:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="locKeySearch" id="locKeySearch" value="" />
</form>
<div id="locDropDown">
    <a href="1">1</a>
    <a href="2">2</a>
    <a href="3">3</a>
    <a href="4">4</a>
    <a href="5">5</a>
    <a href="6">6</a>
    <a href="7">7</a>
    <a href="8">8</a>
    <a href="9">9</a>
    <a href="10">10</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Random anonymous and uncommented downvotes are bad for this community. I cannot see anything wrong with this question, which means I really doubt that a newer user than I is going to. What does this question need?

Comment: @KRyan The original version of the question was not so easy to read :-) but I do agree that a downvote without a comment is not fair - otherwise how can anyone learn what was wrong.

Comment: Ah, well thanks to the Tin Man then.

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved the above query. Below is the answer

```
function keyEvents()
{
    var keyindex,alinks;
    keyindex = -1;
    // Key Events
    $('#locKeySearch').keydown(function(e){
        alinks = $('#locDropDown').find('a');
        if(alinks.length == 0)
        {
            keyindex = -1;
        }
        if(e.keyCode == 40)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            if(alinks.length > 0 && keyindex == -1)
            {
                keyindex = 0;
                $('#locDropDown').find('a')[keyindex++].focus();
            }
        }
    });

    $('#locDropDown').keydown(function(e)
    {
        alinks = $('#locDropDown').find('a');
        if(e.keyCode == 40)
        {
            e.preventDefault();     
            if(keyindex == -1)
            {
                keyindex = 1;
            }
            if(alinks.length > 0 && keyindex < alinks.length)
            {
                $('#locDropDown').find('a')[keyindex++].focus();
            }
        }
        if(e.keyCode == 38)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            if(keyindex == alinks.length)
            {
                keyindex = keyindex-2;
            }

            if(alinks.length > 0 && keyindex < alinks.length && keyindex >=0)
            {
                $('#locDropDown').find('a')[keyindex--].focus();
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: your code has flaws... :) http://jsfiddle.net/pratik136/jnC3T/
 
I'll attempt to correct them after work :)